# Angular 8 multiple filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular7

I am trying to filter any array with multiple filters.

Sample array:

```
array = [
  {"market":"europe","name":"john","Preferences":["1",2"]},
  {"market":"asia","name":"mike","Preferences":["2"]},
  {"market":"europe","name":"tom","Preferences":["1"]}
]
```

binding for the filter values:

```
private market
private name
private preferences: [] = []
```

Function is as below:

```
let filteredResult: any = this.array.filter(u => 
  u.market == this.market && u.name == this.name && u.Preferences == this.preferences)
```

Without filtering with the inside array (Preferences), the function is working properly. But, when I introduce the third parameter (Preferences), the function is returning null.

Sample filter value: (market: europe, preference: ["1")

Any idea what is done wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since your `preference` variable holds an array, comparing two different array with `===`

```
  []  === []
```

Will always return ***false*** as these two array are two different memory references

```js
console.log([] === [])
```

You need to use method like `every` or `some` based on your desired output, if you want to only those element to be included in final output for which all the preferences matches with `this.preference` you need `every` else you need to use `some`

Comment: thanks for your help. I want to return a new array, where it will be matching to all the filters....I tried to use let filteredResult: any = this.array.filter(u => 
  u.market == this.market && u.name == this.name && u.Preferences.every == this.preferences.every), but I am receiving ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'every' of null....am I using the right syntax?

Comment: @AbdalRahmanFarag [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is a method not property, you need to call that method, also before using any array method you need to check whether you value you're operation upon is array or not

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredResult= this.array.filter(u => 
  u.market == this.market && u.name == this.name &&
  u.Preferences && u.Preferences.every(el=>this.preferences.indexOf(el) > -1)
)
```